# Le sens de « trop » dans « je ne savais trop comment la retirer »

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation

Que veut dire *trop* dans la phrase suivante :

> Puis il m'a serré la main qu'il a gardée si longtemps que **je ne savais trop comment la retirer**.

Je pense que le *ne* est peut-être un *ne explétif*. Toutefois, je ne comprends pas le sens de *trop*.

(Si c'est un *ne explétif*, c'est pour quelle raison ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Un équivalent plus habituel est « je *ne* savais *pas vraiment* comment la retirer ». *Ne … trop* connote doute, indécision, absence de choix, ou manque d'alternatives, dans une situation quelque peu embarrassante.

C'est l'une de ces combinaisons formées avec la particule *ne*, comme « ne … plus » ou « ne … rien ». Son emploi est plutôt recherché, mais on l'entend parfois. Par exemple :

> Je ne savais trop quoi faire.

Comment: Dans le jargon québécois, le `Ne ... trop` est devenu `ne ... pas trop`. Exemple: `Je ne savais pas trop comment la retirer` démontre que l'on ne connaissait pas suffisament le sujet, d'où l'incertitude.

Comment: @Jeff: C'est pareil en France, mais dans plusieurs cas, comme « je n'en sais trop rien » ou « je ne peux trop insister », rajouter un *pas* n'est pas possible.

Comment: Fait intéressant (sans vouloir démarrer une discussion)! Dans votre deuxième exemple (au Québec), le *pas* serait totalement accepté oralement: `je ne peux pas trop insister`. Bien sûr, l'intonation peut venir changer le sens et l'interprétation possible de cette phrase.

Comment: @JeffNoel C'est vrai, et c'est semblable ici en France.

Answer (score 4):

Ici, *ne* n'est pas explétif : il exprime la négation et est obligatoire. Quant à *ne (pas) savoir trop*, cela signifie *ne pas savoir avec précision*, *se demander*, ou encore *ne pas voir de solution à un problème*.

Cette phrase signifie *Puis il m'a serré la main qu'il a gardée si longtemps que je me demandais comment la retirer*.

Dans le même esprit, on emploie également *ne pas voir trop* : *s'il y a une panne d’électricité à trois heures du matin, je ne vois pas trop quoi faire.*

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, dans cette phrase, le *ne* n'est pas un *ne* explétif car il est nécessaire à la compréhension de la phrase (phrase négative).

Ici, *trop* peut être remplacé par *pas* :

> « Puis il m'a serré la main qu'il a gardée si longtemps que je ne savais **pas** comment la retirer. »

L'auteur aurait pu également écrire (formule moins soutenue) :

> « Puis il m'a serré la main qu'il a gardée si longtemps que je ne savais **pas trop** comment la retirer. »

Comment: En effet *pas trop* s'utilise aussi, mais ça n'aide probablement pas à comprendre son sens.

Comment: Pour moi si, ça permet de comprendre la formulation et donc le sens de la phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Ce "je ne savais trop" ou "je ne savais pas trop" (plus lourd), est une *figure de style*.

Loin de "savoir trop", le narrateur ne sais *pas du tout* comment retirer sa main.

Mais il ne dit pas "je n'avais aucune idée", il dit juste qu'il n'avait pas un ***surplus*** d'idées. C'est sûr.

C'est une litote. 
https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/litote